# Programmatically generate preview of Adobe files

Tags: javascript, node.js, adobe

I am willing to programmatically generate file previews for a large set of Adobe files. This should be done programmatically (not via user interface via recorded actions).
The idea is to generate jpg/png previews for psd files, pdf preview for indd files and so on.

Is there a library or SDK to easily do that?
I am open to every programming language that can get the job done, however I prefer a js solution since I am willing to run the script on a nodeJS server.

Is there any system requirement or program to be installed to make this thing work? Do I need an Adobe subscription to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find yet a proper solution in JavaScript. But this is a reference link I found on search engines.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11835/pdf-to-jpg-without-quality-loss-gscan2pdf

With ImageMagick on a server, it may help solve the problem.

Another reference link is on about to improve the speed and reduce the memory consumption. This may also help you integrate it on your server.

https://serverfault.com/questions/167573/fast-pdf-to-jpg-conversion-on-linux-wanted

This code snippet may help you. You may have to apply back-ends on your server instead of directly integrating it in your NodeJS server.

```
convert -density 300 file.pdf page.jpg
```